# How to animate login screen transition with provider?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, state-management

I have set up automatic screen change when Firebase auth state change with `provider`.

But there is no animation on screen change. I have try use `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed` but this cause many error.

How to animate automatic screen change when state in model change?
(I have look but no tutorial cover this. All just have no animation on screen change).

Thanks for help!

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (_) => UserRepository.instance(),
      child: Consumer(
        builder: (context, UserRepository user, _) {
          switch (user.status) {
            case Status.Uninitialized:
              return Splash();
            case Status.Unauthenticated:
            case Status.Authenticating:
              return LoginPage();
            case Status.Authenticated:
              return UserInfoPage(user: user.user);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code example of what I think Rémi Rousselet's suggestion is about. The `Provider.of(...)` call triggers a rebuild whenever the authentication status changes, the current screen is set in a switch statement and `AnimatedSwitcher` uses a `FadeTransition` to animate from previous to current screen.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var authenticationService = Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context);

    Widget _currentScreen;

    switch (authenticationService.status) {
      case AuthenticationStatus.authenticated:
        _currentScreen = MainScreen();
        break;
      case AuthenticationStatus.uninitialized:
        _currentScreen = SplashScreen();
        break;
      case AuthenticationStatus.authenticating:
        _currentScreen = LoadingScreen();
        break;
      case AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated:
      default:
        _currentScreen = SignInScreen();
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      home: AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        child: _currentScreen,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Because it will not animate. In a builder of a Consumer<AuthenticationService> put the AnimatedSwitcher with a child as a switch statement. Consumer should be as a home in MaterialApp. If AnimatedSwitcher still not animate a transitions between Screens, add key to every Screen. Key may be needed because AnimatedSwitcher is a stateful widget and can sometimes not recognize that you changed a Widget. You can use ValueKey, for example MainScreen(key: ValueKey(1)), SplashScreen(key: ValueKey(2))

Answer (score 1):

Using `provider`, animations are performed the same way you'd do with any widgets.

There are a few solutions:

- [ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget-class.html)
- [didUpdateWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html)
- [didChangeDependencies](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Element/didChangeDependencies.html)

All of these approaches consist of comparing the between the new and previous state.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am look for example how to implement because I cannot see how to use implicit animation for animate so many screen without many code.

Comment: That's too broad.

Comment: I have post my code in question. There is no simply way for animate this screen change? (I ask because every open source app I see have no animation for this part but it is bad UX)